# How can I find the answers I gave in a Jhipster project?

Tags: jhipster

I am trying to find what were my answers to the questions on an old Jhipster proyect and I can not find how to see them in the configuration of the project.

Is there a file were I can check if whether I choose to use JHipster Registry or not, Angular or React, Maven or Gradle? Of course, some of the choices can be found looking at the files, but is there any specific config file that saves the answers?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `.yo-rc.json` file in your project